# Change the label of UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to change the font of UIPickerView.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel()

    label.font = UIFont(name:"SynchroLetPlain", size:20)
    //label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17) //Even I use systemFont, it doesn't show nothing
    return label
}
```

It is ok for compile though, no text is shown.

Where is defferent? I have checked SynchroLetPlain is included in project.

Comment: What's the postscript real name of your font? That's the one to use.

Comment: I have tried font name as @Anthon suggested below 'Synchro LET Plain' however still have no luck

Comment: `label` has no frame?

Comment: No frame setting, This is the whole source of `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {`

Comment: Does it work systemFont at least?

Comment: I added the source code , even I use system Font it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var label: UILabel
        if let view = view as? UILabel {
            label = view
        } else {
            label = UILabel()
        }
        label.font = UIFont(name:"SynchroLetPlain", size:20)
        // where data is an Array of String
        label.text = "" // set data here
        return label

    }
```

Additionally:

```
func printFonts()
    {
        for fontFamilyName in UIFont.familyNames {
            print("-- \(fontFamilyName) --", terminator: "")
            for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamilyName ) {
                print(fontName)
            }
            print(" ", terminator: "")
        }
    }
```

Call this function, which gives you the exact name of the font which you have to use to set the font.

Comment: This works for me, I don't set the label.text ="" before.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
label.font = UIFont(name:"Synchro LET Plain", size:20)
```

I guess the problem is related to actual name of a font. I mean that iOS search font by it actual name, not the file name of the font.

**Update:**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var label: UILabel
    if let view = view as? UILabel {
        label = view
    } else {
        label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name:"SynchroLetPlain", size:20)
    }
    label.text = "text" // your text
    return label
}
```

Comment: Please make sure what you implemented necessary delegate methods. Like  `pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?` Also I suggest checking this tutorial http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/